# Is there GEM/Software/API that can be used to add every town in the world to a auto-complete form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, full-text-search, search-engine, startup

I'm building a startup called Airlifte.com. It will have a search form as the home page very much the same as Kayak.com. My question is when someone searches for a place e.g. a town or city, is there a way for the form to run auto-complete from a database that has every town/city listed that exists in the world?

So if I start typing in London e.g. Lon it will automatically start to make suggestions. For everything with Lon in it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.rubygeocoder.com/

Geo Coder for Rails is perfect for this. Also checkout ut http://railscasts.com/episodes/273-geocoder?view=asciicast.

Erin

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use the full-text search of the DB.  In MySQL you can use wildcard queries such as "lon*" to do prefix search.  You can use other software packages, including open-source packages such as Lucene and commercial packages for higher speeds.